# Open and Close Dropdown menu on by mouse hover in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React JS.
My problem is that I want the menu to disappear if the mouse leaves that area, so I tried `onMouseOut` and `onMouseLeave` to close the menu but it seems that when this option is there the menu never opens! But when I remove the `onMouseOver` or Leave then it works fine but just stays there if you don't click something.
**MenuListProps={{ onMouseLeave: handleClose }}**

That happens because when I open the menu, a modal layout is placed over the whole page, which means the `onMouseLeave` event will be fired immediately after `onMouseEnter`. but for it to work I must change the menu anchor so that it covers the button in its entirety

```
<div>
            {menuItem.map((text) => (
              <Button               
                onClick={(e) => handleChangeMenu(text, e)}
                onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(text, e)}>
                {text}            
              </Button>
            ))}
            <Menu
              transitionDuration={700}
              anchorEl={project}
              open={Boolean(project)}
              onClose={() => {
                setproject(null);
              }}
              MenuListProps={{
                onMouseLeave: () => {
                  setproject(null);
                },
              }}
            >
              {mySubMenu.map((text) => (
                <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle}>{text}</MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: use event `onmouseover="yourFunction($event)"`

Comment: `onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(text, e)}` i used it like this @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Consider using CSS instead of JS for hover interactions

Comment: Is there any possibilities in reactjs ? and  could you share me the example ? @evolutionxbox

Comment: `.myElement:hover .child { display: block; }`

Comment: this medium article helped me with a nextui dropdown issue, maybe it can point you in the right direction. https://medium.com/@rwchampin/nextui-dropdown-on-hover-open-close-nextui-dropdown-component-on-hover-9733b1572480

Answer (score 0):

There is exists specified material component [ClickAwayListener](https://mui.com/base/api/click-away-listener/).

You can add mouse leave event handler like this

```
 <ClickAwayListener mouseEvent="onMouseDown" onClickAway={handleDropdownClickAway}>{your menu code}</ClickAwayListener>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situations i am using onBlur, had same issue, add onBlur event to your Menu component

```
onBlur={() => {
   setproject(null);
}}
```

Ussually i have in state a constant that holds the value to show dropdown or not, below is how i do in my projects

```
const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
const showOption = (): void => {
    setShowOptions(!showOptions)
}

const onBlur = (): void => {
    setShowOptions(false)
}

const onMouseDown = (): void => {
    setShowOptions(false)
}

// here adding all events to your menu
// if u decide to use a constant to tell u to show dropdown, than pass showOptions as a prop inside YourMenu compoennt and hide show your dropdown using showOptions constant
<YourMenu                    
    onClick={showOption}
    onKeyDown={showOption}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    showOptions={showOptions} // prop to show hide your dropdown
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `div` as a container of `Button` and `Menu`, and add att. `onMouseLeave` to it.

```
<div>
    {menuItem.map((text) => (
       <div key={text}
            style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
            onMouseLeave={() => setproject(null)}    // <== Here
       >
            <Button               
                onClick={(e) => handleChangeMenu(text, e)}
                onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(text, e)}
                id={text}                            // <== Here
            >
                {text}            
             </Button>
             <Menu
                 transitionDuration={700}
                 anchorEl={project}
                 open={Boolean(anchorElBtn) && anchorElBtn.id === text}     // <== Here
                 onClose={() => {
                   setproject(null);
                 }}
            >
              {mySubMenu.map((text) => (
                <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle}>{text}</MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
       </div>
   ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the event that hide the menu

```
onMouseLeave: () => {
   setproject(null);
},
```

only happens on `<Menu` element

a possible solution is here

1. add the same event to `<Button` element so that it hides the menu when mouse leaves its area

- I assume `<Button` is from an external ui library. You may need to check properties to make sure `onMouseLeave` works

```
<div>
  {menuItem.map((text) => (
    <Button               
      onClick={(e) => handleChangeMenu(text, e)}
      onMouseOver={(e) => handleHover(text, e)}>
      {text}
      onMouseLeave={() => setproject(null)}        
    </Button>
  ))}
  <Menu
    transitionDuration={700}
    anchorEl={project}
    open={Boolean(project)}
    onClose={() => {
      setproject(null);
    }}
    MenuListProps={{
      onMouseLeave: () => {
        setproject(null);
      },
    }}
  >
    {mySubMenu.map((text) => (
      <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle}>{text}</MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Menu>
</div>
```